# Convert integer to display full date in words/text

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm trying to obtain a full date given a string such that 03-30-1986 will result to March 30, 1986.

I have tried the following code.

```
$date = 03.30.1986
$mydate = strtoTime($date);
$printdate = date('m-d-Y', $mydate);
```

I used echo to view the result of $printdate but it turns out its value is null. Thoughts?

Comment: Why are you trying to store this value in a numerical variable when it should be a string? The function name is short for STRING to time, so make it a string.

Comment: $date = '03.30.1986';
$mydate = strtoTime($date);
echo $printdate = date('F d, Y', $mydate);// March 30 1986,

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = '03.30.1986';
$mydate = strtoTime($date);
echo $printdate = date('F d, Y', $mydate);
```

this is work just add quote...

```
Result :March 31, 1969
```

Comment: Mine still doesn't work. I assigned $bday = string($row['user_bdate']) from the database and did alterations for the $bday's value to become 03.30.1986. $printdate doesn't print anything so I'm guessing it's value is null.

Comment: strtotime can accept in format of date.
can you show me the return value user_bdate maybe there wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts:

- [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) requires a string: `$date = "03.30.1986"` (note the `str` part of the function name)
- PHP expressions are delimited with a `;`: `$date = "03.30.1986";`
- You need to reformat the [date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to: `"F d, Y"`

So your code becomes:

```
$date = "03.30.1986";
$mydate = strtoTime($date);
$printdate = date('F d, Y', $mydate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  first line has several errors(missing quotes, semicolon), strtotime can't parse that date format and you are using wrong format for desired output. This should work:

```
$date = '03.30.1986';
$parts = explode('.', $date);
$mydate = mktime(0, 0, 0, $parts[0], $parts[1], $parts[2]);
$printdate = date('F d, Y', $mydate);
```

Comment: Now it doesn't work. It prompts a warning that says Warning: mktime() expects parameter 5 to be long, string given. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '03.30.1986';

$temp = explode('.',$date);

$date = date("m.d.Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $temp[0], $temp[1],$temp[2]));

echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

php assume it as Europian date format. for more please see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
```